# JSONObject -- Retrieve Arbitrary Property

Tags: java, json

I was trying to debug the following code that can retrieve an arbitrary property of a JSONObject.

It fails when trying to access JSON more than one level deep.
For instance if the JSONObject passed in is called "node" and it has a "subnode" which has a property, it fails.

So in the example, there is an accessor "`node.subnode.property`".

I think what happens is that

```
record = ((JSONObject)record).get(key);
```

is returning a string -- record is not a `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` at that point.
So the next time through the for loop it doesn't find the property.

What is the best way to fix this?  The method shouldn't have nay knowledge of the content of the JSONObject being accessed.

```
  public final Object getJSONValue(JSONObject jsonObject, String accessor)
  {
    String[] keys = accessor.split("\\.");
    Object record = jsonObject;

    for (String key : keys)
    {
      if ((record instanceof JSONObject))
      {
        record = ((JSONObject)record).get(key);
      }
      else if ((record instanceof JSONArray))
      {
        record = ((JSONArray)record).get(Integer.parseInt(key));
      }
      else
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return record;
 }
```

Note that I'm using `org.json.simple.JSONObject`;

Comment: Could you provide an input for which your function returns incorrect result?

Comment: The else if ((record instanceof JSONArray)) can never execute.  The type of jsonObject is JSONObject (as defined in the parameter list) so the if ((record instanceof JSONObject)) test will always be true.  Same applies to the final else (it can't happen).

Comment: I would suggest to raise an exception in the "else" block. Because the only reason execution will reach this branch is if "accessor" contains incorrect sequence of fields. The second reason is that you probably would like to distinguish between failure case (incorrect accessor) and a case when a value of a field is null.

Comment: Don't cast `jsonObject` to `Object` and use than `jsonObject#getJsonObject()` for properties access and then `getValueType()` to determine properties type. It's type safe variant.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Unfortunately getJsonObject() isn't available in the org.json.simple.JSONObject that I use.  I did get it to work by sending the string returned by get(key) back through the JSONParser -- although the code to do that looks messy.